# Regex to match a-z spaces, character limit, only first letter capitalized

Tags: php, regex

I need some help with a regex. I'm terrible at this.

Rules:

- Only letters a through z and spaces
- Minimum 2 letters
- Maximum 30 letters
- Each word must be at least 2 letters
- Only the first letter of each word *may* be capital but the first letter must *always* be capital

My attempt:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{2,30}$
```

I'm using this in PHP.

Comment: [This should get you started.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) But much more importantly: which language/tool are you using this regex in?

Comment: The first three rules are well within the capability of a regex. However, the 4th rule will prove to be a challenge if you're attempting to use a single regex for all four rules.

Comment: @nickb the fourth one alone is not a problem either, and orthogonal requirements can be combined with lookaheads *if* the flavor provides them. hence, my question for the OP

Comment: It's not often I get downvoted... Apparently, I'm misunderstanding something. Could you clarify what you mean by your fourth requirement?

Comment: @pete I mean that "My name Is bob" would be a match and "My naMe Is bob" wouldn't

Comment: @PopeyeDoyle - What about consecutive spaces? Is more than one space between words permitted?

Comment: do spaces count towards the `2..30` range?

Comment: @m.buettner yes sir forgot to add that!

Comment: @PopeyeDoyle so "2 to 30 **characters**" in total? in that case I can cut out the more complicated half of my answer ;)

Comment: Yes space should be treated as a letter. So "Hey The Re" would be 10 "letters"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so let's try solving requirements 1 to 3 first. If you mean 2 to 30 *characters* it's as simple as this:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$
```

Now for the other requirements. Let's handle those alone. Point 4 requires each word to be of the form `[a-zA-Z][a-z]*`. To make sure that each word has at least two letters, we can simply turn the `*` into a `+` (which means 1 or more repetitions). If we insert explicit spaces around these, that makes sure that the `[a-z]+` cannot be followed directly by a capital letter:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ ]+[a-zA-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

Note that I treated the first word separately.

Finally, how do we combine the two? By putting one into a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). I'm going for the counting here:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$)[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ ]+[a-zA-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

This works because, after the input is checked against the lookahead the engine resets it "cursor" to where it started (the beginning of the string) and continues matching as usual. This way we can run two passes over the input, checking for independent conditions.

Finally, note that the lookahead requirement simply translates to the string's length. In such a case it would be easier (and most often better) to check this separately:

```
$len = strlen($input)
if ($len < 2 || $len > 30)
    // report error about string length
else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[ ]+[a-zA-Z][a-z]+)*$/', $input))
    // report error about pattern
else
    // process input
```

This makes it much easier to give sensible error messages depending on which condition was violated.

Comment: amazing simply amazing. you know your regex. thanks alot! really

Comment: @PopeyeDoyle :) have a go at the tutorial I linked in my first comment on your question. By the end of the weekend, you'd come up with patterns like this by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
^[A-Z]((?<= )[A-Z]|[a-z ]){2,29}$
```

---

```
[A-Z]          -- a capital letter
(
  (?<= )[A-Z]  -- either a capital letter preceded by a space
  |            -- or 
  [a-z ]       -- a lowercase letter or a space
){2,29}  -- 2 to 29 times (plus the initial capital)
```

You will need to use the PCRE (not `ereg_*`) for the lookbehind to work.

```
"My name Is bob"
   ↑  ↑  ↑
   |  |  \-- this is a "(?<= )[A-Z]"
   |  \--- this is a "[a-z]"
   \---- this is a "[ ]"


"naMe"
   ↑
   \-- this is NOT a "(?<= )[A-Z]" (a character before the [A-Z] is not a space)
```

EDIT: damn, you added the "Each word must be at least 2 letters". Use `m.buettner`'s.

Comment: The 30 needs to be 29 otherwise you'll allow a 31-character string.

Comment: You could fix yours for the two letter requirement: `^[A-Z][a-z]((?<=[ ])[A-Z]|[a-z]|[ ](?=[A-Za-z]{2})){2,29}$` or something along those lines ;)

Comment: Nah, at this point I don't think it's wise to use regexps. I'd match with `^[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Za-z][a-z]+)*$` and check the length separately.

Comment: @PavelAnossov yeah, that's much better as long as you don't have some kind of framework, where all you can do is provide a single validation regex (which is probably not the case here)